# Как настроить отображение ошибок в PHP?

Tags: php, apache2

подскажите пожалуйста, как включить отображение ошибок в PHP Apache2 прямо в браузере? Добавлял в php.ini display_errors = on, перезагружал компьютер - не помогло... Сейчас при ошибке у меня отображается это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://track24.ru/google/?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%20php

Comment: это может быть ошибка апача. ну или вы редактируете не тот php.ini

Comment: Могу ещё предположить, что вы работает с каким-нибудь OpenServer и там редактируете неправильный файл

Comment: Всем спасибо, пришлось покопаться в гугле, нашёл!